# Как логировать необработанные исключения в Python?

Tags: python, логирование

Имеется скрипт на питоне, запускается планировщиком заданий в Windows 10.

Использую модуль `logging`, но он не пишет необработанные ошибки.

Как логировать необработанные исключения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) для отлова необработанных исключений и пишите в логгер сообщение об ошибке.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c289d2d383812cf8b5ca9b5a25b5a863f5e34790/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L24):

```
import traceback
import sys

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    # Или
    log.error(text)

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

1/0
```